# Does Sage Pay have a PayPal-like IPN?

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, opayo

I'm building an events system where users can book & pay for tickets - I'm intending to use Sage Pay Form, and have all transaction data held on their servers (I would collect ticket order, customer name & address on the website, then have them POST it to Sage Pay).

The only information I need 'my end' is confirmation that payment has been received, so I can simply mark a ticket as sold (most events will have limited tickets).

I've worked with PayPal IPN (& PDT) before, and wondered if Sage Pay offers a similar notification service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the FORM protocol on the REQUEST you indicate the callback url, you will be notified on that URL when the payment is completed.

**SuccessURL** *The URL of the page/script to which the user is redirected if the
transaction is successful. You may attach parameters if you wish.
Sage Pay Form will also send an encrypted field containing
important information appended to this URL (see below).*

You also need to specify the FailureURL, in case the transaction fails.

Comment: AFAIK, your `SuccessURL` is only notified if the user chooses to navigate back to your site.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The PP IPN calls your server in the background itself, whereas SagePay will redirect the user to SuccessURL with a parameter containing the result. This is an issue as the client's internet connection could drop before reaching the page, or the client could close their browser before they reach that URL. This leaves the transaction in a state were the customer has paid, but you are not notified of it. This is very hard to detect (usually results in disgruntled customers). This should be a consideration for anyone thinking of using SagePay form integration.

Answer (score 0):

Sage Pay also allow confirmation of failed and successful transactions via email if you pass a field **VendorEMail=**john.smith@webdeveloper.com in your transaction posts.  This is listed as an optional field in their integration protocol.